# String is unassigned after Label in c#

Tags: c#, string, goto

I have an issue that I totally not understand:

In the following code, the string `path` is used. path works in front of the lable, but afterwards its unassigned. Confusingly to me, all other variables work!

Code:

```
path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";
File.WriteAllLines(path + incident + "\\result_" + incident + ".txt", resultText.ToArray());
End:;
File.WriteAllLines(incident, resultText.ToArray());
File.WriteAllLines(path + incident + "\\result_" + incident + ".txt", resultText.ToArray()); // issue at path in this line
```

[image]

> Use of unassigned Variable...

I could reassign the variable after the lable but then i always have to edit 2 lines of code in case of change

Comment: What's with the image?

Comment: this little `End:;` thingy.... where is the rest of it ? and please post also the declaration of `path`

Comment: End: is a label so there is a goto branch where the variable is not initialized. Also consider Path.Combine()

Comment: You probably have a `goto End;` somewhere. When you come in that way, `path` isn't assigned a value. Gotos are notoriously hard to keep track of, which is why they were classified as 'evil' 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you have:

```
string path;
```

Make it

```
string path = null;
```

and it fixes your problem.

---

Although it's assigned `null`, the path is not unassigned at the label.

But, since I come to think of it, maybe you meant:

```
string path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";
```

That way, it is assigned and has a valid value from the beginning.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/exz4PR):

---

#### example

```
    string path;
    goto End;
AnotherLabel:
    path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";
    Console.WriteLine(path);
End:;
    // issue at path in this line
    Console.WriteLine(path);
```

#### fix

```
    string path = null;
    goto End;
AnotherLabel:
    path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";
    Console.WriteLine(path);
End:;
    // no issue at path in this line
    Console.WriteLine(path);
```

#### suggestion

```
    string path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";
    goto End;
AnotherLabel:
    Console.WriteLine(path);
End:;
    // no issue at path in this line
    Console.WriteLine(path);
```

#### advise

```
    // don't use labels, due to these kinds of obscurities ;-)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is your label - this allows a code path that jumps to your "End" label that allows "path" to not be set.

2 easy solutions:

- Reassign "path = @"C:\incidents\jobTransfer";" after the "End" label - which you mentioned is problematic, as you'd have two places to edit code if change.  (although, if you parameterize it in some sort of config file, you could change it once).
- Place the label above the original assignment of "path" and use some conditional to skip your "File.WriteAllLines(path + incident + "\result_" + incident + ".txt", resultText.ToArray());" if its not desired.

A better solution would be to not use labels at all - these are usually frowned upon, and your problem is one of the many reasons why; although, before everyone jumps down your throat for using goto, there are some arguably acceptable [reasons to use it](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/acceptable-uses-for-the-goto-statement-in-C-Sharp/).

Answer (score -1):

As you're using a Label - which is uncommon in C# above this label is essentially one scope and after it is another - so the variable declared is no longer in scope so this is why it is no longer assigned, you'll need to declare this variable outside of the use of the label - or not use a label at all as this isn't usual practice in C#

Comment: Labels have function scope, if this were a scope issue the variable would not exist rather than simply being uninitialized.

Comment: Indeed, it could still be declared elsewhere and because it's initialised in one scope and used in another - not used labels ever in C# so wasn't sure, just knew it was possible but not seen until this question